# I'm getting ''none'' instead of result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

Hi im a beginner python user. I coded a thing just for practice but im getting ''none'' instead of the result. code is like this :
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNFE5.png)

i think im using str function wrong but i dont know how to fix it.
thanks for your help

Comment: Please post the **code**, not the **images** of the code

Comment: It is because you are not returning anything. When you don't return anything, a function returns ```None``` by default. Hence the result

Comment: what Python version are you using, and are you running this in bigquery?

Comment: Using `Retrun` instead of `print()` will definitely help!

Answer (score 3):

See, when you don't use the `return` keyword, a function returns `None`. So when you print a function which returns `None`, Then `None` will be printing.

So, use the `return` keyword.

```
def work_time(mathematic, chemistry, biology): 
    print(mathematic*2 + chemistry*1 + biology*(0.5))
    return mathematic*2 + chemistry*1 + biology*(0.5)
print("I will study " + str(work_time(1, 2,3) ) + " hours today")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an image or code
but things that can result to none can be:-
1.Not returning a blue from function
2.Keeping a boolean inactive
3.Not defining codes

Answer (score 0):

you should use `return` instead of `print`

```
def work_time(mathematic, chemistry, biology): 
    return mathematic*2 + chemistry*1 + biology*(0.5)
print("I will study " + str(work_time(1, 2,3) ) + " hours today")
```

Answer (score 0):

none is telling you that the function is not returning a value so you must use the **return** keyword